# Queues in TI-SYSBIOS

Tags: c

I am trying to use Queues in my project. Below is a simple example from TI.

```
void mailbox_queue(void)
{
    MsgObj msg; // create an instance of MsgObj named msg
    Msg msgp;   // Queues pass POINTERS, so we need a pointer of type Msg
    msgp = &msg;// init message pointer to address of msg
    msg.val = 1;// set initial value of msg.val (LED state)

    while(1){
        msg.val ^= 1; // toggle msg.val (LED state)
        Semaphore_pend(LEDSem, BIOS_WAIT_FOREVER);// wait on semaphore 
        Queue_put(queue0, (Queue_Elem*)msgp);   // pass pointer to Message 
        Semaphore_post (qMsgSem);       // unblock Queue_get to get msg
    }
}

Problem statement:
```

mailbox_queue task is pending on the semaphore LEDSem. Once this semaphore is posted, 
I am placing the msg on Queue and post a semaphore to signal the receiver side.

The issue i am running into is, while the msg object is local, even before the receiver
gets the msg.val value, there is a high chance that msg.val could be written to a new value.
Also, Cert-C strongly recommends not to pass the pointers of local variables or structs.

One way i could solve this is to declare msg struct as static but this would make a copy which would 
consume space on RAM.

Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Greatly appreciate that.

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour. This is a fundamental issue not only in C and not just a minor flaw. And where do you think the struct will bne placed other than in RAM?

Comment: well my argument is if i put the msg struct as local, it will be on stack (Temporary) but I guess this would work as I am trying to pass a pointer. Basically my intention is not to duplicate memory.

Comment: Sorry, but I really hate when someone tries to discuss about a fact. Try jumping out of a window and discuss with gravity. And there is no need for a stack in the C language.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Mailbox](http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/sysbios/6_31_04_27/exports/bios_6_31_04_27/docs/cdoc/ti/sysbios/knl/Mailbox.html) instead, that takes a copy of the input data to pass to the receiving function.

In my experience most of the problems that happen in multi-threaded programs come from sharing memory between threads.  Don't pass pointers, pass actual data to the destinations.  If you pass pointers, you then have to protect the contents until the destination has finished with it, which means a load more semaphores etc.

(Reading up on Communicated Sequential Processes may be enlightening.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but using mailbox would be a copy based where I have to make a copy of the structure in every function that I would declare it. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: My experience is that making copies is a win from a development point of view.  As I said, if you don't do this you have to add protections.  For larger data structures I have created managed  structures which avoid the copying but do the protections for me (effectively cross-thread FIFOs where you "checkout" a slot in the FIFO, push data in and then "release" it).  You may need a Semaphore per slot depending on how you are using it, or just a single semaphore to protect the whole structure.  But then the semaphores can become the bottleneck instead...

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but IMHO the most natural thing to do would be to use a dedicated `HeapBuf` to allocate elements in the producer and deallocate them in the consumer. That should keep the advantages of the queue (no copying) and remain sane implementation- and overhead-wise.